# Perimeter of "Touching" Hexagons

Tags: geometry, area

I am interested in learning about if there is a way to calculate the Perimeter of "Touching" Hexagons.

For instance, I that the perimeter of single hexagon can be calculated as follows:

[image]

So if we have two "non-touching" hexagons with side length "a1" and "a2", the perimeter of both hexagons is : 6*a1 + 6*a2

However, once the hexagons are touching, the perimeter changes. For instance, consider :

- two touching hexagons of same side length "a"
- two non touching hexagons of same side length "a"

[image]

It becomes evident that the perimeter for touching hexagons is not the same as the perimeter of non-touching hexagons - the perimeter of non-touching hexagons is 1.2 times greater than the perimeter of touching hexagons.

I also noticed that depending on how the hexagons are touching, the perimeter can be different:

[image]

However - it also becomes evident that the surface area for the same number of "touching" hexagons does not depend on how they are touching.

This leads me to the following question:

- **Do we have any general formulas that allow us to calculate the perimeter for "n" number of touching hexagons:** Would this depend on how the hexagons are "touching" - or does the "way they are touching" become irrelevant in calculating the perimeter for a  "large numbers of touching hexagons" (e.g. see below) ?

[image]

- We know that the general formula for the surface area of a hexagon is (3*sqrt(3)/2)*a^2 . We can use this formula to calculate the ratio between the perimeter and the surface area of a single hexagon (ratio: 6a /  (3*sqrt(3)/2)*a^2 = 4/(sqrt(3)*a) = 2.309*a). **Do we know what this ratio of perimeter to surface area if for an infinite number of "touching" hexagons?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No such formula exists. Your example with 3 hexagons already shows this. But the situation is worse than you might suppose.

Suppose you compare the "approximately rectangular" arrangement of hexagons in your picture to a different arrangement where the hexagons are all strung out in a line: it should be pretty obvious that the perimeters are quite unequal.

In general, for $n$ hexagons, it's not hard to construct an"approximately square" arrangement whose perimeter has the form $O(\sqrt{n})$, and an "approximately linear" arrangement whose perimeter has the form $O(n)$.

In fact, one can prove rigorously that the absolute minimal perimeter of an arrangement of $n$ hexagons is $O(\sqrt{n})$ and the absolute maximum is $O(n)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Can you please explain what you wrote here about O(n) and O(sqrt(n))? I am using to seeing O(n) represent "computational complexity" (e.g. Landau Notation : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: I posted a similar question over here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4384157/understanding-the-honeybee-conjecture-vs-sphere-packing-conjecture) - I am trying to better understand why the ratio between the "perimeter and the surface area" of infinite hexagons is equal to the "fourth root of 12" - can you please help me understand this? Thank you so much!

Comment: The "computational complexity" meaning is exactly my intention. Notations like $O(n)$ and $O(\sqrt{n})$ are used to describe how functions grow in a qualitative sense.  Given a function $c(n)$, to say that $c(n)$ "has the form $O(n)$" means that $K_1 n \le c(n) \le K_2 n$ for some constants $K_2 \ge K_1 > 1$; and to say that $c(n)$ "has the form $O(\sqrt{n})$" similarly means $K_1 \sqrt{n} \le c(n) \le K_2 \sqrt{n}$.